# Can an uncountable set be the union of countably many subsets that aren’t equinumerous to the uncountable set itself

Tags: set-theory

If an uncountable set, say A, equals a countable union of subsets of A - is it true that one subset of A must be equinumerous to A?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For $n\in\Bbb N$ say $A_n$ is a set with cardinality $\aleph_n$ and let $A=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$. (Hmm, that says the answer to the question in the body of the post is no, while the answer to the question in the title is yes...) A slicker way to say more or less the same thing: Say $A$ has cardinality $\aleph_\omega$.

Or, if you're not familiar with those $\aleph$ things, but you know that a power set of $S$ is always larger than $S$: Let $A_1=\Bbb N$ and let $A_{n+1}$ be the power set of $A_n$, and again set $A=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$...

(With either construction we have $|A|\ge|A_{n+1}|>|A_n|$, so $|A|\ne|A_n|$.)

Comment: Sorry if I confused you. My question is the one in the body. I.e. if A is the union of A_n where for all natural numbers,n, and A_n strictly dominated by A.  Can This possibly be true,

Comment: I don’t understand the N things. Also I’m confused about the use of power sets because the power set of A isn’t a subset of A.

Comment: @Anteater23 Try reading it again - the power set of $A$ has nothing to do with it... (I'd try to answer your question but right now I don't see what to say except repeat what I already said.)

Comment: I understand how the cardinality increases as n increases but I don’t get how the union of these power sets equals A.

Comment: @Anteater23 $A$ is _defined_ to be the union of those power sets. (Maybe this was not clear;  I added it explicitly to  the power-set version just now...)

Comment: That makes more sense now

Comment: The cardinality of a power set is $2^n$ where n is cardinality of the powerset. So if $N$ is countable, would that not make every powerset countable and hence their union countable.

Comment: @Anteater23 What??? I would have thought that the first thing you'd learn about this stuff was that $P(\Bbb N)$ is uncountable! I guess not. $P(\Bbb N)$ is uncountable, now you know. Yes, if we say $\aleph_0=|\Bbb N|$ then $|P(\Bbb N)|=2^{\aleph_0}$. And yes, $\aleph_0$ is countable. I don't know why you think it follows that $2^{\aleph_0}$ is countable, but it's not so. In fact $2^\kappa>\kappa$ for _every_ cardinal $\kappa$; hence $2^{\aleph_0}>\aleph_0$, so $2^{\aleph_0}$ is uncountable.

Comment: @Anteater23 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem

Comment: How do I know each $A_n$ Is strictly dominated by A if $A_1$ is the set of natural numbers? Also why is it written that the cardinality of $A_{n+1}$ is less than or EQUAL to that of A?

Comment: @Anteater23 The point is to show that $|A|>|A_n|$, as required. We know that $|A|\ge|A_{n+1}|$ because $A_{n+1}\subset A$. We know that $|A_{n+1}|>|A_n|$ because $A_{n+1}=P(A_n)$. Hence $|A|>|A_n|$. Yes, $A_1$ is the set of natural numbers. So what? That has no effect on the argument that I can see..